# ps aux does not shows the process started using docker

Tags: docker

I'm following a tutorial where the author runs a Nginx container using docker and when the author does `sudo ps aux | grep nginx` and `sudo docker ps`, it shows up the Nginx process running for both commands.

When I do the same,

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx                            latest              16666ff3a57f        2 years ago         108MB

$ sudo docker run -d -it nginx:latest
1a67431e100da4d655b69879efe19a7e7f05adb34a0619bd3501d0f4a51010ae

$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1a67431e100d        nginx:latest        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        80/tcp              gracious_bhabha

$ sudo ps aux | grep nginx
sjeeva     50895   0.0  0.0  2442020    808 s002  S+    4:54PM   0:00.00 grep nginx
```

Why am I not seeing the docker nginx process in `ps aux`, while I'm seeing the nginx process for `docker ps`?

EDIT::
Works fine in a ubuntu machine. This problem is in my mac.

Comment: `docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' gracious_bhabha` should give you the actual PID. From there, you should be able to find it in the list of processes

Comment: When I use the command you specified, I get the PID. But when I search that PID in `ps aux`, its not listing any process with that PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I not seeing the docker nginx process in ps aux, while I'm
>   seeing the nginx process for docker ps?

The `docker` for Mac uses a Virtual Machine (unlike linux). That means that it has been installed on a virtual machine and not on your Mac host, so when you hit `ps aux`, it's listing the running processes on your **host** and not the processes inside the virtual machine.

[Here](https://www.bretfisher.com/docker-for-mac-commands-for-getting-into-local-docker-vm/) you can find some options to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the process with container id.

```
ps aux | grep 1a67431e100d
```

Comment: that does not work either. 

`sjeeva:~ sjeeva$ ps aux | grep 4725d0983366
sjeeva     63191   0.0  0.0  2443044    832 s002  S+   12:09PM   0:00.00 grep 4725d0983366`